# Checking for zero length array from JSON set

Tags: ios, json, nsarray, nsdictionary, nsmutabledictionary

I have  JSON data set returned that I am parsing.

If the data contains a record it looks like this:

```
dictData: {
    Recordset =     (
                {
            Record = (
                                {
                    MyDate = "2016-06-15 11:04:43";
                    MyID = 53070;
                    SomeDescription = "";

                }
            );
        }
    );
}
```

If the data does ***NOT*** contains a record it looks like this: 
**Notice the "" in the return set which is causing me issues.**

```
dictData: {
    Recordset =     (
        ""
    );
}
```

I am having trouble accounting for the zero length array in the Recordset.

Here is my base code for parsing the data.

```
NSDictionary * dictData = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:[someOtherDictionary objectForKey:@"Data"]];
NSArray * arrRecordSet  = [dictData objectForKey:@"Recordset"];

if([arrRecordSet objectAtIndex:0] != nil) {
    NSLog(@"CONTAINS RECORDS");
    //Do something with the records
}
else {
    NSLog(@"DOES NOT CONTAIN RECORDS");
}
```

I have tried various iterations of things like checking if `[arrRecordSet objectAtIndex:0]` length is greater than zero or checking the count size.

I think the double quotes are throwing me off.

Any help?

*UPDATE*

RAW JSON as requested

**ONE RECORD**

```
{
    APIResponse =     {
        Data =         {
            Recordset =             (
                                {
                    Record =                     (
                                                {
                            MyDate = "2016-06-15 11:04:43";
                            MyID = 53070;
                            SomeDescription = "";
                        }
                    );
                }
            );
        };
    };
}
```

**NO RECORDS**

```
{
    APIResponse =     {
        Data =         {
            Recordset =  (
                               ""
            );
        };
    };
}
```

Comment: When you log the arrRecordSet.count what does it say ?

Comment: It shows a count of 1. If 1 record is returned it also shows a count of 1.

Comment: can you show a valid JSON as an example instead of console log of your parsed nsdictionary?

Comment: @arturdev i have updated the question to include the raw JSON

Comment: whoever has designed that server side was not a professional at all, but what you can do is to check whether the `"Recordset"`'s array has a `String` item and if it has not then you can check for `Dictionary` items.

Comment: Ha you took the words out of my mouth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in the case of success the `Recordset` value is an array with a dictionary and in the case of failure the `Recordset` value is an array with a string.

So:

```
NSArray *recordSet = response[@"APIResponse"][@"Data"][@"Recordset"];
if ([recordSet count] > 0 &&
    [recordSet[0] isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
    // Success
    NSDictionary *record = recordSet[0];
    ...
} else {
    // Failure
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This was the way to go checking for isKindOfClass!

Answer (score -1):

Here you should check first all key for dictionary **Recordset** if it returns you count>0 then you can say data is available and if not then there is a blank entry.